# Rails | Group by count of multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by

I have a Country model with name, school and branch columns.
I want to find out the unique number of schools and branches in a country.

I expect the result to be in this format:
{"India" => [25, 100]}

```
//{Country => [No.of unique schools, No.of unique branches]}
```

I want to calculate this value once in the controller (instead of doing something like below in the view).

```
Country.all.each do |country|
 cs = Country.where(country: country).uniq.pluck(:school).count
 cb = Country.where(country: country).uniq.pluck(:branch).count
end
```

I am able to group one column by count like this

```
Country.group(:school).order('count(school) desc').count
// {"India"=>31, "USA"=> 50 }
```

How can I do the same on multiple columns?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So in your `countries` table, you have multiple occurrences of the same country (i.e. "India" could appear several times but with different school and branch data)?

Comment: @jeffdill2 Yes, the country will appear several times but with different school and branch data